# Would serial correlation be problematic if only the regressors are serially correlated in a multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, assumptions

In this regression:

$Y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_{1t}+ \beta_2 X_{2t} + ... + \beta_p X_{pt} + \epsilon_t$

If there is serial correlation among e.g. $X_{1t}$, what would be the consequence?

Answer (score 0):

When we estimate the model parameters, we minimize the errors $\epsilon_t$. When auto-correlations is present, then $\epsilon_t$ are not what we should minimize - we should minimize errors after accounting for the correlations.

There are number of problems when we simply fit a multiple regression model. For one, the model parameters estimated are not the best estimates. (You may do better by  regression with ARIMA errors). Also, number of statistical tests (like t-test of model parameters) and model selection criteria (AICc) will not be valid.

---

You find a better description [here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/estimation.html).

Comment: I think your answer is more about the serial correlation among the dependent variables.

Comment: It is about if the $\epsilon_t$ are autocorrelated. I think if $X_i$'s autocorrelated, a linear combination of them is very likely to be autocorrelated as well.

Comment: Unless the $\epsilon_t$ are autocorrelated, it shouldn't matter $X_i$'s being autocorrelated.